# How to convert json object to string and replace text

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, replace

I would like to convert my json to a string then find and replace substrings like so using JQuery

```
var data = JSON.stringify(object).text();
data.text(data.replace("meat", "vegetables"));
console.log(data);
```

This gives me

> JSON.stringify(...).text is not a function

How can I fix this.

Comment: For future reference: there is a JavaScript object, and then there is its JSON (string) representation. There isn't anything called a _JSON object_.

Comment: @Andy I also feel that you're right, but [check those examples](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4627#page-7)

Comment: @Andy JSON stands for javascript object notation, yes there isn't such thing as a JSON object as that would be javascript object notation object. But I think everyone understands what I meant when I said JSON object. See here: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_objects.asp

Comment: Yes. But the issue is that _you_ didn't understand that because you wanted to convert something that was _already_ JSON into a string - you were using confusing terminology, either from something you read, or from a colleague etc. I'm saying the best way to stop making that error is to elimnate the term altogether.

Comment: @Andy point taken

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`JSON.stringify` is already a text (string), that's what `stringify` means (turn to a string), just omit the `.text()`:

```js
var object = {"food":"meat","quantity":"10"}
var data = JSON.stringify(object); // this is a string
data = data.replace("meat", "vegetables");
console.log(data);
```

Comment: this gives me data.text is not a function

Comment: @Stuwart I updated my answer, I didn't see that before, I concentrated on `JSON.stringify(object).text()`.

Comment: @Stuwart `.text()` is used to get the text content of HTML DOM Elements such as `<div>` `<span>` ...etc, `data` is a string, a JavaScript string, such as `"Hello, World!"`.

Answer (score 1):

The method `stringify` returns `string` and the type `string` doesn't have the method `text`, so just update the first line to the following:

```
 var data = JSON.stringify(object);
```

also update the second line with the following:

```
data = data.replace("meat", "vegetables");
```

Comment: Code-only answers are not useful. [Please explain what you did](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).